# How to merge dictionaries as columns in a DataFrame, collecting values from matching keys grouped

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

| Number | Metadata |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | {key1: x1, key2: y1} |
| 12 | {key1: x2, key2: y2} |
| 12 | {key1: x3, key2: y3} |
| 13 | {key1: x4, key2: y4} |
| 13 | {key1: x5, key2: y5} |

How can I end up with the following?

| Number | Metadata |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | {key1: [x1, x2, x3], key2: [y1, y2, y3]} |
| 13 | {key1: [x4, x5], key2: [y4, y5]} |

I tried something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for d in (d1, d2): # you can list as many input dicts as you want here
        for key, value in d.items():
```

But not sure how to group by the Number column in the process

Comment: can you share that DF as a code? shouldn't the key and value be in quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
>>>
def merge_dicts(g: pd.DataFrame):
    dd = {}
    for d in g.Metadata:
        for k, v in d.items():
            dd[k] = dd.get(k, []) + [v]
    return dd


grouped = df.groupby('Number')
out = grouped.apply(merge_dicts).reset_index(name='Metadata')
print(out)

    Number  Metadata
0   12      {'key1': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'key2': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']}
1   13      {'key1': ['x4', 'x5'], 'key2': ['y4', 'y5']}
```